# Why .swf files not opening in Chromium's Flash Player of Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, flash, chromium

I have `browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash pepperflashpulgin-nonfree` for Chromium in my system. I cannot anymore just start the flash animations in the browser. It just downloads the animations when directing URL to the file or opening it directly in the browser.

Cloacker's answer proposal about apt-get is what I did first in troubleshooting.

### Studying internal difference in Ubuntu 16.04 and Debian 8.5

All answers (1-3) here are insufficient and/or not working. 
Bigger problem here is that Debian can solve the case with less packages than Ubuntu, please see the thread [Why internal differences in Flash Player of Ubuntu and Debian?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/288715/why-internal-differences-in-flash-player-of-ubuntu-and-debian) 
The command fixes the case in Debian 8.5

```
apt-get install browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash
```

However, Ubuntu 16.04 requires one more package, which I want to understand why, since it does not make sense

```
apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash
```

System: Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit
Linux kernel: 4.4-4.7
Internet browser: Chromium 51.x, Google Chrome 52.x

Answer (score 0):

Pepperflash is for chromium browser only. If you have this installed, you could try:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get remove browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash pepperflashpulgin-nonfree
```

and then. again:

```
$ sudo apt-get install browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash
```

Comment: Yes, I am using it there but it stop working. Starting animation just downloads it. Your proposal is exactly what I did already in troubleshooting first but not helping.

Answer (score 0):

with chromium shut down, try reseting chromium profile:

```
$ cd ~/.config/google-chromium/
$ mv ./Default ./Backup\ Default
```

Open again and try...

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2218732&page=2&p=13040642#post13040642), try to run the following script

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "Update file freedesktop.org.xml...";
sed  -e "s/<mime-type  type=\"application\/vnd.adobe.flash.movie\">/<mime-type  type=\"application\/x-shockwave-flash\">/g"  /usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml >  /usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml.new
mv /usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml /usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml.original
mv /usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml.new /usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml
echo "File updated successfully!";
echo "Update mime database...";
update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
echo "Mime database updated successfully! ALL DONE!";
```

Which means to copy the entire script in a text editor, save as `~/swfscript.sh` and then in a terminal

```
chmod +x ~/swfscript.sh
~/swfscript.sh
```

Comment: Your command `sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime` gives `Unknown media type in type 'all/all' Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'`. I also run without `sudo` unsuccessfully.

Comment: That is not a problem, it is just a warning.

Comment: Doing it does not solve the problem. I still have the same problem in opening .swf file unsuccessfully in Chromium.

Comment: Did you try to reboot?